# How to make loop for panels background color from a module VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in a module in VB.NET
so pp1 is a panel

```
    Public Sub changecolor(ByRef curruntpanel As Panel)
        On Error Resume Next
        Main_Form.PP1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        Main_Form.PP2.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        Main_Form.PP3.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        Main_Form.PP4.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        Main_Form.PP5.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        Main_Form.PP6.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        Main_Form.PP7.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        Main_Form.PP8.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        Main_Form.PP9.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        Main_Form.PP10.BackColor = SystemColors.Contrl

        curruntpanel.BackColor = Color.White
    End Sub
```

and I want to replace it with loop code so I tried the next code but it's not working with me

```
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To 10
            Main_Form.Controls("pp" & i).BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        Next

        curruntpanel.BackColor = Color.White
```

this code in a module too
So can anyone give me the right code for loop?

I want help to turn into some lines to loop code

Comment: You should remove the `On Error Resume Next` - you want it to tell you when and where something goes wrong.

Comment: Get rid of `ByRef`.

Comment: Oh, and the line `Main_Form.PP10.BackColor = SystemColors.Contrl` would never have worked: it should be `.Control` with two "o"s.

Comment: Add Main_Form.Show().  If you now see two forms, one with the expected colors, then you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `Name` of the control in the loop from, `pp` to `PP`. Here's an example:

```
Public Sub changecolor(ByRef curruntpanel As Panel)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        Main_Form.Controls("PP" & i).BackColor = SystemColors.Control
    Next
    curruntpanel.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah i am sorry it's not working with me bro i wish if i can fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Pass the instance of the form where your panels are contained.

```
Public Sub changecolor(ByVal formInstance As Form, ByVal curruntpanel As Panel)
    For Each ctrl As Control In formInstance.Controls
       If TypeOf ctrl Is Panel Then
          If CType(ctrl,Panel).Name.StartsWith("PP") Then
             CType(ctrl,Panel).BackColor = SystemColors.Control
          End If
       End If
    Next
    curruntpanel.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

Comment: should i replace "formInstance " by my form name like Form1?

Comment: No. It should be the declaration of an instance of your form

Comment: ok THANK YOU  i will try it today and i will tell you